# How to Store Randomly Selected date Value in Jquery Calender

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code:

```
<div id="calendar"></div>    
    Date:<input type="text" id="datepicker_send" name="datepicker_send" readonly="readonly"  >
    <script>
        $('#calendar').datepicker({
            altField: '#datepicker_send',
                inline: true,
                firstDay: 1,
                showOtherMonths: true,
                dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']
        });
    </script>
    <script>  
        var x = document.getElementById('datepicker_send').value;
        document.write (x);    
    </script>
```

Textfield date is changing when we click on other date but var "**`x`**" is giving the default todays date only.

I want the changed dates in calender to be stored in "**`x`**" live.

Can anyone help how to solve this case?

Answer (score 0):

Try appending changeDate function to the calendar whose date you need on change..
Example,

```
$('#calendar').datepicker({

altField: '#datepicker_send',

    inline: true,

    firstDay: 1,

    showOtherMonths: true,

    dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']

}).on('changeDate', function() {
  document.write ($('#datepicker_send').val());
});
```